# ExpandableListView в отдельном классе и его вызов оттуда

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Есть класс

```
public class AdapterHelper
{
final String ATR_GROUP_NAME = "gropuName";
final String ATR_PHONE_NAME = "phoneName";


String groups[];


String g_item[];



ArrayList<Map<String,String>> groupsData;


ArrayList<Map<String,String>> childDataItem;


 ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String,String>>> childData;


Map<String,String> m;

Context ctx;

AdapterHelper(Context ctx, String groups[],String g_item[])
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.groups = groups;
    this.g_item = g_item;
}

SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter;

SimpleExpandableListAdapter getAdapter()

{
    groupsData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (String group : groups)
    {
        m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        m.put(ATR_GROUP_NAME, group);
        groupsData.add(m);
    }


    String groupeFrom[] = {ATR_GROUP_NAME};
    int groupTo[] = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

    childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>();



    childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (String phone : g_item)
    {
        m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        m.put(ATR_PHONE_NAME, phone);
        childDataItem.add(m);
    }
    childData.add(childDataItem);


    String childFrom[] = {ATR_PHONE_NAME};
    int childTo[] = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

    adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(ctx, groupsData, simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            groupeFrom, groupTo, childData, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, childFrom, childTo);

    return adapter;
}

String getGroupText(int groupPos)
{
    return ((Map<String,String>) (adapter.getGroup(groupPos))).get(ATR_GROUP_NAME);
}

String getChildText(int groupPos, int childPos)
{
    return ((Map<String,String>) (adapter.getChild(groupPos, childPos))).get(ATR_PHONE_NAME);
}

String getGroupChildText(int groupPos, int childPos)
{
    return getGroupText(groupPos) + " " + getChildText(groupPos, childPos);
}}
```

Хочу вызывать в MainActivity, что бы при каждом вызове добавлять группу и строки.

```
 private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
 private AdapterHelper ah;
 private SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter;

 String groups[] = {"Group_1"};
 String g_string[] = {"String","String_1","String_2"};

 ah = new AdapterHelper(this,groups,g_string);
 adapter = ah.getAdapter();


 expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Всё добавляется. Но только для одной группы. Что переделать что-бы при каждом  отдельном вызове, добавлялась новая группа с строками? У меня в итоге добавляется только то, что было вызванно последним.

```
    String groups[] = {"Group_1"};
    String strings_1[] = {"String_1","String_2","String_3"};

    String groups1[] = {"Group_2"};
    String strings_2[] = {"String_1","String_2","String_3"};


    ah = new AdapterHelper(this,groups,strings_1);
    ah1 = new AdapterHelper(this,groups1,strings_2);

    adapter = ah.getAdapter();
    adapter = ah1.getAdapter();


    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Т.е не добавляется, а перезаписывает существующую группу.

Решил попробовать следующее:
 В конструктор добавить второй параметр, к примеру String g_item_2[], а в сам  метод второй вызов

```
childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
for (String phone : g_item_2)
{
    m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    m.put(ATR_PHONE_NAME, phone);
    childDataItem.add(m);
}
childData.add(childDataItem);
```

получилось что если вызывать

```
    String groups[] = {"Group_11","TEST"};

    String strings_1[] = {"String_11","String_2","String_3"};

    String strings_2[] = {"String_1","String_2","String_3"};

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    ah = new AdapterHelper(this,groups,strings_1,strings_2);
    adapter = ah.getAdapter();
```

то добавляет как надо. Но это не то, идет дублирование кода во первых, а во вторых теряется весь смысл, как выход использовать цикл, в котором идет перебор добавляемых массивов строк в конструкторе. И вот тут то проблема, не могу понять как соорудить этот цикл, а точнее как во второй итерации, подставить следующий массив строк. К примеру:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 2; a++) //Кол-во массивов строк в конструкторе
{
childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    for (int a =0; a < g_item.length; a++ )
    {
        m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        m.put(ATR_PHONE_NAME, g_item[a]); 
        childDataItem.add(m);
    }
    childData.add(childDataItem); }
```

т.е добавится первый массив g_item. Как в следующую итерацию подставить следующий массив g_item_2 ?

upd:
Сделал следующее:

```
String test[][];
```

в конструкторе добавил

```
AdapterHelper(Context ctx, String groups[], String[]... test)

SimpleExpandableListAdapter getAdapter()

{

    groupsData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>();
    // childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    for (int a = 0; a < groups.length; a++) //String group : groups
    {
        m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        m.put(ATR_GROUP_NAME, groups[a]);
        groupsData.add(m);


        for (int i =0; i <test[a].length; i++ )//String phone : phonesHTC
        {
            //childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>();
            childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put(ATR_PHONE_NAME, test[a][i]); //phone
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);
       // childDataItem.add(m);

    }
```

...
Получается что группы создаются, но в них добавляются только последние элементы передаваемого массива. Ошибка где-то в цикле. Не могу понять где именно.

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужен хелпер для операций со списками. Так вы сами себя запутали.
Вы да, сначала один адаптер создаёте с одними данными, а потом другой и его назначаете списку.

Вам надо лишь хранить ссылку на список/мапу с данными в адаптере, добавлять данные в этот список/Map и уведомлять адаптер о изменениях в данных.

1. Создайте класс-адаптер
2. Создайте в нём поле для хранения данный типа `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`
3. Создайте в адаптере метод добавления данных (метод `put(String key, ArrayList<String> value)` класса `HashMap`)
4. Сразу после добавления вызовите `notifyDataSetChanged()` метод адаптера.

Т.е. у вас одна переменная для адаптера, один адаптер и одна переменная для хранения данных. Вы добавляете в последнюю данные и уведомляете адаптер о них.

Comment: Будьте добры пример, если есть. Спасибо.

Comment: @Kamenev_D, примера нет, но алгоритм написал.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, после чтения инета, выяснил что notifyDataSetChanged() не работает с ExpandableListView, а предназначен для работы с ListView.

Comment: @Kamenev_D, ну, попробуйте тогда другой метод http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#deferNotifyDataSetChanged()